# Display state by mapstate from vuex store

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, vuex

Hello I want to display mainTab.HPval for example 
I got in my store state and object inside

```
  mainTab: {
      HPval: 10,
      MANA: 0,
      'type': ''
  },
```

I definied

```
computed: {
     ...mapState(['mainTab'])
},
```

And If I want to display it says undefinied

```
     <Label :text="'heal ze Store = '+ mainTab.HPval" />
```

[1 ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbQ1T.jpg)

[2ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAPlI.jpg)

Comment: I hope you are ideally creating a `Vuex.Store` with the exported values from `inputValues.js`. It should work, do you have a sample project on Github where this issue can be reproduced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `mainTab` is a module as per the attached screenshot and to access the module state variable, you need to write it like below.

```
...mapGetters("module_name", ["variable1", "variable2"]);
```

So, In your case,

```
...mapGetters("mainTab", ["mainTab"]);
```

You can find Reference [here](https://github.com/varit05/chocomama/blob/master/src/components/Cart.vue)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see your `mainTab` state variable is defined inside a module. To access module's state from store, you have to do something like this.

```
computed: {
    ...mapState({
        mainTab: state => state.YOUR_MODULE_NAME.mainTab
    })
},
```